# How can I make xml from complex dictionary in Python?

Tags: xml, python-3.x

I want to make recursive function to generate xml from complex dictionary (i.e. dictionary of dictionaries, for example

`dataDict = {'item1': 'this in item1', 'item2': 'this in item2', 'item3': 'this is item3'} rootDict = {'name': 'Daud', 'code': 'MC111011', 'data': dataDict}`).

This is what I have tried,

```html
from lxml import etree

def dict_to_xml(dictData):
    for key,val in dictData.items():
        if isinstance(val, type(dict)):
            child = dict_to_xml(val)
            if child is not None:
                yield from child
        else:
            yield key, val
            child = etree.Element(key)
            child.text = str(val)
        return child


# create XML
dataDict = {'item1': 'this in item1', 'item2': 'this in item2', 'item3': 'this is item3'}
rootDict = {'data': dataDict}
for key, value in rootDict.items():
    if isinstance(value, type(dict)):
        childElement = dict_to_xml(value)
    else:
        childElement = etree.Element(key)
        childElement.text = str(value)


root = etree.Element('root')
root.append(etree.Element('child'))
# another child with text

root.append(childElement)


# pretty string
s = etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True)
print(s)
```

I am getting the following output

```
b"<root>\n  <child/>\n  <data>{'item1': 'this in item1', 'item2': 'this in item2', 'item3': 'this is item3'}</data>\n</root>\n"
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

```
from dicttoxml import dicttoxml

dataDict = {'item1': 'this in item1', 'item2': 'this in item2', 'item3': 'this is item3'}
rootDict = {'name': 'Daud', 'code': 'MC111011','data': dataDict}

xml = dicttoxml(rootDict, custom_root='myXML', attr_type=False)
print xml
```

Output is:

```
<myXML><code>MC111011</code><data><item2>this in item2</item2><item3>this is item3</item3><item1>this in item1</item1></data><name>Daud</name></myXML>
```